# not sure why code is printing out only the first movie

Tags: c++, vector

Hi im trying to use a vector to store a list of movies but when i try to cout the movies i only get the first one. i am not sure why the code is doing this. if anyone can help it wold be great thanks.

```
Movies::Movies(string fn){loadMovies(fn);}

 int Movies::getMovieCount() const {return movies.size();}


 const Movie * Movies::getMovie(string mc) const {
Movie* p = *movies.data();
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < movies.size(); i++)
{
    if(p->getTitle().find(mc) ==string::npos)
    {
        cout<<string::npos;
        printf("test:%d\n",i);
        return p;
    }
    p++;
}
return NULL;
}

 Movies::~Movies() {
for(std::vector<Movie*>::const_iterator ptr = movies.begin(); ptr != movies.end(); ptr++)
{
    delete *ptr;
}
}

void Movies::loadMovies(string fn) {
ifstream iS(fn);  // technically should be c_str
string s;
getline(iS, s); // skip heading
getline(iS, s);
while(!iS.eof()) {
    Movie* m = new Movie(s);
    movies.push_back(m);
    getline(iS, s);
}
iS.close();
sort(movies.begin(), movies.end());
}
```

Comment: Use the debugger to step though the code and see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't going to work

```
Movie* p = *movies.data();
```

Incrementing this pointer will NOT move it to the next element of the vector, but to some random location. Besides working with vector's representation directly is a VERY bad idea.

Also `find` returns `npos` if it didn't find anything, so you need to change your condition.

Here is a  proper way to implement the search

```
const Movie * Movies::getMovie(string mc) const
{
  for(auto I = moves.begin(); I != movies.end(); ++I)
  {
      if((*I)->getTitle().find(mc) != string::npos)
      {
          return *I;
      }
  }
return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use C++11 feature such as `auto`, why not use the C++11 range-based loop? I.e. `for (const auto* movie : movies) { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

The line `Movie* p = *movies.data();` gets you the first pointer from the vector (in an odd way). However, `p++` does not get you the next pointer, but changes `p` to point to the space  *after* the first movie, not the next movie.

I think it would work better if you just skipped the pointer `p` and used

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < movies.size(); i++)
{
    if(movies[i]->getTitle().find(mc) ==string::npos)
    {
        cout<<string::npos;
        printf("test:%d\n",i);
        return movies[i];
    }
}
```